# How to write lambda for java.UnaryOperator<T> interface in Scala?

Tags: scala, lambda

I've written this code in scala:

```
def push(x: T): Unit = ref.updateAndGet(new UnaryOperator[List[T]] {
  override def apply(t: List[T]): List[T] = x :: t
})
```

And want to rewrite it in a more functional way, like

```
def push(x: T): Unit = ref.updateAndGet(t => x::t)
```

But it doesn't work. Is it possible to do such casting correctly?

Comment: version and result? `def f[A](a: A)(g: UnaryOperator[A]) = g(a) ; f("hi")(_ * 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scala 2.12 (RC 1 has already been released) this will be done automatically (i.e. `ref.updateAndGet(t => x::t)` will just work). In Scala 2.11 this already exists but under `-Xexperimental` compiler flag and the support is incomplete (I don't know the exact limitations).

Answer (score 7):

[scala-java8-compat](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat) has java8 function converters

```
import scala.compat.java8.FunctionConverters._

def push(x: T): Unit = ref.updateAndGet(asJavaUnaryOperator(t => x::t))
```